# Were Spaniards threatened with terrorist attacks by an ISIS leader if they didn't vote Unidos Podemos?

Tags: politics, terrorism

[La Tribuna del Pais Vasco](http://latribunadelpaisvasco.com/not/4816/el-estado-islamico-amenaza-a-los-espanoles-con-nuevos-atentados-si-no-votan-a-podemos/) [Spanish text] reports that Abu Bakr Al-Magrebi threaten Spanish citizens with terrorist attacks unless they voted for [Unidos Podemos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unidos_Podemos), a left-wing political organisation.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=y&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Flatribunadelpaisvasco.com%2Fnot%2F4816%2Fel-estado-islamico-amenaza-a-los-espanoles-con-nuevos-atentados-si-no-votan-a-podemos%2F&edit-text=) explains:

> Abu Bakr Al-Magrebi, one of the leaders of the self - styled Islamic State in northern Africa, made ​​public last June 10 a statement in which, without citing urges Spanish citizens to vote can and in which warns of "consequences" that could have for Spain to ignore the threats of this organization.
>   "So far, none of the apostates parties they have been voting and paying taxes has wanted to really change its position regarding the oppression that the Muslim people have been suffering for centuries by the West. We know that they have recently arisen forces the Spanish society that are openly opposed to this injustice and are willing to compensate us, "says Abu Bakr Al-Maghrebi. He adds: "For your interest, and to avoid actions as thanks to Allah could run in New York, Madrid, Paris, London and Brussels, we have to take into account these new options in other countries have to reproduce proved so effective in destroying the structures of power and have changed their political course ".
>   If there is any doubt of his implicit reference to Podemos, the party led by Pablo Iglesias, Abu Bakr Al-Magrebi recognizes that while this formation in its day was funded by the takfiris Iran (Shiite enemies of the Sunni Islamic State) , "we believe are the best solution to this situation that has been reached by your imprudence, indecency and continued abuse."

On that article it references [this evidence from Site Intelligence Group](https://news.siteintelgroup.com/Jihadist-News/pro-is-group-publishes-message-threatens-citizens-of-spain-ahead-of-general-election.html). I have read that they are reliable in their claims.

Can you help me to either confirm or discard this claim?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42334/discussion-on-question-by-user34735-were-spaniards-threatened-with-terrorist-att).

Answer (score 3):

This [article from La Informacion](http://noticias.lainformacion.com/disturbios-conflictos-y-guerra/terrorismo/Difunden-falso-comunicado-EI-Podemos_0_925708727.html) concludes it is fake, and explains why.

Translation:

> - The text has been prepared with the sole purpose of creating noise and tension between the Spanish population.
> - The name of the signatory of the document, whose name is not on any database of members or prominent supporters of the Islamic State, also has the problem of being misspelled, something that never happens with a name in Arabic, even when write with Latin characters. In fact, Baker does not exist in Arabic but would be Bakr, in the same way, which in Latin characters Magrebi is written Maghrebi. In both cases, misspellings are considered sufficient to deny credibility to it.
> - The document has not been published by al-Wafa Media Foundation as it is not on their official website, and neither is the document that appeared on 31 May. The latter does not appear on the list of Historic Foundation, either.
> - It is considered that such actions are nothing but an attempt, by some individual, to create confusion among the Spanish population and spread fear of a possible attack, which is fairly unlikely.-- The intent of the document is no other then to establish a relationship between the political party and Islamist terrorism.
> - Although the name of the political party is not expressly cited, there is enough information to determine that it would be the political group Unidos Podemos.
> - This document lacks any truth because the Islamic State, and therefore radical Islamist movements, do not recognize democratic states as a political form of operation.
> - Precisely one of the criticisms constantly made from communication channels directed by Islamic State is the democratic functioning of the West, because they are considered to be apostate ways associated to infidel countries.
> - It's the first time in the history of an Islamist movement that, despite going against their most basic beliefs, calls for the vote for a political party, regardless of the ideological current that it represents.
> - It is a contradiction, on the other hand, that with this statement the Islamic State or any related parties, ask the vote for someone who, according to the document has received funds from an enemy state of the terrorist organization like Iran.
> - References to Ceuta and Melilla are but a maneuver to introduce more noise, as never before the Islamic State has referred to the location of military units in the two autonomous cities. Generally, the Islamic State never speaks of Ceuta and Melilla but of Al-Andalus, with the ultimate goal of its conception as Great Caliphate.
> - It is considered, finally, that the document is a maneuver to destabilize a critical moment in the political life of Spain, which does not represent a threat to state security and has been prepared with a specific purpose for a specific moment in time.
> - Likewise, it is estimated that such documents will become more common in the coming days.

The report that reaches these conclusions was prepared by a private security consultant company called AICS, according to the article.